# "Edit source" button for Google Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to quickly test and debug Google Chrome extensions. Is there any way to add an "edit source" button next to each extension on the Chrome Extensions page, using an extension?
[image]

Comment: If this isn't possible, then are other testing/debugging tools for Chrome extensions available?

Answer (score 0):

The [TamperMonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) allows all installed userscripts to be viewed and edited within Chrome- this is the best "work-around" that I've found for this problem so far. I don't yet know whether it can synchronize scripts between Chrome installations - hopefully this feature will be implemented soon.